# Finding an element in array, whose index number and element value same

Tags: algorithms

Given a sorted array of distinct integer $A[1,2.....n]$ the tightest upper bound to check the existence of any index $I$, for which $A[I]=I$ is equal to _______________ ?

---

I thought here answer that mean time complexity will be $O(1)$, because directly getting the searching index and then checking if $A[I]=I$, but answer given as $O(log n)$.

Please help me out, which will be correct answer?

Comment: You have to _find_ i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array had $A[i]=i, \forall{i}$, then the complexity would have been $\theta(1)$ as then all we need to check whether the length of the array is greater than the element or not. If it's greater we have the element, else we haven't.

But the array isn't like that. Array could be like $1,3,4,8,9,12$ as well.

The question is asking to find an element $A[i]$ in the sorted list which is situated at the index $i$.

The algorithm to find such element is mere a slight modification of binary search where you update low & high based on $i<A[i]$ - if it's true update `high=mid-1` else if $i>A[i]$ update `low=mid+1`.  The complexity is indeed $\theta(log_2n)$

Comment: Is binary search always take an element a[I]=I?? ok, tell me one thing , if in this algorithm, I want T.C.=O(1), what modification needed for this code?

Comment: @Srestha You can't achieve in $O(1)$ time. E.g, 1,4,6,9,12 (index starting with 1)

Comment: Mr. Sigma, I have not got the point. Here it is told a[I]=I, that means a[1]=1, a[2]=2,a[3]=3......only this type of sequence possible here. Then how r u telling a[1]=1,a[2]=4, a[3]=6 .... is a possible sequence.

Comment: @Srestha Your question specifies that the input is a sorted array of distinct integers - it does not specify that, in the input, $A[i] = i$. If this is the case you should update your question. However, this would make the problem trivial.

Comment: no, that was not question, I just want to know, what my fault is?

Comment: @AcId yes array can be any thing, if array element is other than this, then it will return false, is not it? Say, if array is 1,4,6,9,12 , then the existence of any index I, say I=5 and a[5]=5? answer will be no and it will return. Do we need to check each and every index here?Plz make this doubt clear

Comment: @Srestha You have understood the question wrongly. Question involving $A[i]=i, \forall{i}$ would be very trivial.

Comment: @Srestha No, it is not necessary to check every index. As stated in the answer, we can use a modified binary search (because the input is sorted), an thus only have to check $\log_2 n$ indices.

Comment: Mr. Sigma, "[]=,∀ would be very trivial." I have not got meaning of it.Can u explain a bit?

Comment: @AcId "we can use a modified binary search (because the input is sorted), an thus only have to check log2 indices." I have not got it. Can u tell me then why not O(1)? I understand it is a sorted list , but just we need to 1 element from the list, why not this thing not correct?

Comment: @Srestha updated the question. $\forall{i}$ means for all $i$

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. Sorry, if we need to find every I , then ans should be $O(n)$, as we are checking each and every element here. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. My doubt is coming because like binary search it is not checking only a element, but it is checking element with an index. Is not it? In binary search we find if an element present or not  in log n time. But here we are checking, if an element present in a particular index?If yes, then element present for that index, otherwise element not present for that index only. Why do we need to check other index of array, for that element? Then why do we need (log n) time??

Comment: @Srestha okay, do one thing. Make a new array $B$ where each element in the array is $A[i]-i$. Now find out $0$ in the array $B$. the position of $B$ would be the position where $A[i]=i$

Answer (score 1):

Take the hints. The integers can be positive or negative, but they are *distinct*. The array is sorted, which usually means a1 ≤ a2 ≤ a3 ... But the are distinct, so a1 < a2 < a3 < ... And they are integers, so they are at least 1 apart. So we have a2 ≥ a1 + 1, a3 ≥ a2 + 1, a4 ≥ a3 + 1 and so on. What does that mean for ai - i?

(If you figure that out, the solution is trivial).

Comment: Plz check my above comment. I understand everything except , what a[I]=I is doing? Is it checking every I or it checking a particular I?

Comment: Srestha, you are supposed to either find an i such that a[i] = i or demonstrate that such an i does not exist. You could check is a[1]=1? Is a[2]=2? And so on but that is slow.

Comment: "either find an i such that a[i] = i or demonstrate that such an i does not exist. "-if I does not exists, we have to check every I in O(n) time. Is not it?

Comment: I am getting either O(1) time , or O(n) time, but not getting O(log n), because it is not checking only a element, but it is checking element with an index

Answer (score 0):

The best searching method for this problem will be binary search and in binary search time complexity of avg or worst case is logn.
and if in question it is not mentioned distict intergers then we can't apply binary search then it we go with linear so in that case time complexity will be o(n).